# Iterate through mongoose find result

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have some trouble getting out data from the result of a query in mongoose: here is my function:

```
getNinjas : function(res){
    var twisted = function(res){
        return function(err, data){
            if (err){
                console.log('error occured');
                return;
            }
            res.send('My ninjas are:\n');
            for (var i;i<data.length;i++){
                console.log(data[i].name);
            }
                            //I need to process my data one by one here
        }
    }

    Ninja.find({},'name skill',twisted(res));
}
```

So if I `console.log(data)` in the getNinjas function, I get the result of my query. How can I access each record one by one? I get nothing in the console like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `i`:

```
for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
//        ^^^^
  console.log(data[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you ask how to access each record one by one, it's good to have `forEach` in your arsenal other than the standard `for` loop. Once you've crossed the error checking `if`:

```
data.forEach(function(record){
    console.log(record.name);
    // Do whatever processing you want
});
```

Comment: Mongoose query results are objects not arrays, so they do not have a `forEach` method.

Comment: throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined